# How to specify ec2 instance types for different services?

Tags: juju, amazon-ec2

After I have specified a default EC2 instance type for my Juju charm, how do I override that for one of the services?

For instance, the [Juju tutorial](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/user-tutorial.html) deploys wordpress and mysql, and I can set the **default-instance-type** in my *environments.yaml* so both services are **m1.small**

But how do I configure it so that (only) the mysql service gets deployed on an instance type better suited to a database, like **m2.xlarge** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In summary, if you wanted to deploy with m2.xlarge:

```
 juju deploy mysql --constraints 'instance-type=m2.xlarge'
```

Or if you want your deployment script to be more portable between providers:

```
 juju deploy mysql --constraints 'mem=8G'
```

Here are the corresponding documents:

- https://jujucharms.com/docs/2.0/reference-constraints

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll try and keep an eye on the Launchpad updates.

Comment: I see that juju in Ubuntu 12.04 has the constraints feature now, and I can specify a default architecture, memory, or type for a  whole environment, and then change it for a single service. **Good work!**