# How do I specify an AMI in Juju?

Tags: juju, amazon-ec2

This solution no longer works [How to specify ec2 instance types for different services?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101005/how-to-specify-ec2-instance-types-for-different-services-in-a-charm) since using the default-image-id option in the environments file has been deprecated.It mentions in the documentation that we can use constraints but what should be the key. I tried different ways like

- `juju bootstrap --constraints "image-id: ami-xxxxxxxx"`
- `juju bootstrap --constraints "default-image-id: ami-xxxxxxxx"`
- `juju bootstrap --constraints "ami-image-id: ami-xxxxxxxx"`

but it didn't work. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I'll update that question with the answer, I hadn't even realized that feature had been deprecated!

Comment: Hey have you tried using `default-image-id:` anyway? I know it's deprecated but I think it should still work.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it says "Your environments.yaml contains deprecated keys; they must not be used other
than in legacy deployments. The affected keys are:

    default-image-id"